# About sorting based on the counting of subelements

Tags: xml, xslt

i have an xml document with properties that belong to agencies:

```
<agency name="Century 42" num="Century42" mail="century42@gmail.com"/>
<property agency="Century42" ....>
...
```

I would like to print the info of all agencies. The agencies should be sorted by the number of properties that they own.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="immo/agency">
<xsl:sort select="count(//property[@agency=@num])"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

The count is not valid.

Comment: Please (1) show us a **complete** example of the XML input, and (2) indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a key in order to count the properties in the sort instruction.  A stylesheet containing the following:

```
<xsl:key name="p" match="property" use="@agency"/>

<xsl:template match="/immo">
   <result>
      <xsl:for-each select="agency">
         <xsl:sort select="count(key('p', @name))"/>
         <res id="{ @name }" count="{ count(key('p', @name)) }"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </result>
</xsl:template>
```

when applied to the following input:

```
<immo>
   <agency name="a"/>
   <agency name="b"/>
   <agency name="c"/>
   <property agency="a"/>
   <property agency="a"/>
   <property agency="a"/>
   <property agency="b"/>
   <property agency="b"/>
   <property agency="b"/>
   <property agency="b"/>
   <property agency="c"/>
</immo>
```

produces the following output:

```
<result>
   <res id="c" count="1"/>
   <res id="a" count="3"/>
   <res id="b" count="4"/>
</result>
```

If you want the opposite order, use `order="descending"` on `xsl:sort`.

**EDIT**: If `property/@agency` can have several agency numbers, separated by whitespaces, the following solution works instead (not using keys though, and selecting all properties in the documents again for each agency):

```
<xsl:template match="/immo">
   <result>
      <xsl:for-each select="agency">
         <xsl:sort select="count(//property[tokenize(@agency, '\s+') = current()/@name])"/>
         <res id="{ @name }"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </result>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: what if a property may belong to several agencies (using idrefs) ? How to sort agencies in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I received a simple answer to my question

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="immo/agency">
<xsl:sort select="count(//property[contains(@agency, current()/@num)])" order="descending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: Be careful with `contains`.  Is it impossible to have an agency code that is a substring of another one?  E.g. `century21` and `century21.branch12`.  Or `century` and `century21`.